# phpQuery - Get data from table with no class or id

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm trying to get some data from a table, where the  tag has no id, class or any other attribute that can identify it.

The table structure is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><b>Type</b></td>
    <td>Plug and Play</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Model</b></td>
    <td>AH591Z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Date</b></td>
    <td>02.04.2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td>CryptMachine</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>ID</b></td>
    <td>9283</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How would I for example get the Model, Name and ID but ignore the date and type, because I don't need those values.

Is there a smart way to do this with phpQuery? So far I've just played around with the phpQuery library, but i definitely got the basics down, I just cannot wrap my brain around this.

Comment: What database are you using? if mysql in the query `select model, name, id from tableName`

Comment: Looks to me like he is scraping data from an existing site that he has little control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but something like this maybe?

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($theDocument);
$table = $doc["table"];
$model = pq($table)->find("tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)")->text();
$id = pg($table)->find("tr:eq(4) td:eq(1)")->text();
```

If there is more than one `table` on the page, you may have to use eq(n) to specify which one, remember that they are enumerated from 0, not 1.

UPDATE: If you don't know the order of the rows, you could use something like this (again, untested, sorry, but should get your pointed in the right direction)

```
<?php

function getValue($table, $label) {
    $lable = strtolower($label);
    $rows = pq('tr', $table);

    foreach($rows as $row):
        if ( strtolower(pq($row)->find('td:eq(0)').text() ) === $label ):
            return pq($row)->find('td:eq(1)').text();
        endif;
    endforeach;
}

$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($theDocument);
$table = $doc["table"];

$model = getValue($table, "Model");
$id = getValue($table, "ID");

?>
```

Comment: Is there any way that you can you fetch the value, when you have the index?
Something like: find type or find id

Comment: Sure, you can loop through the `tr`s, then grab the first `td`, check if it contains the text() "ID" or "Model" or whatever, and if so, you can then grab the next `td` and exit the loop, right?